# "Failed to open stream" error, when creating new migration

Tags: php, yii, yii-migrations

I'm trying to use the yii migration system but I'm stuck on this error when I execute this command:

```
   ./yiic migrate create basic_data_migrate
```

I get this error:

```
PHP Error[2]: file_get_contents(C:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.28-0\apache2\htdocs\cv360\protected\migrations\template.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
    in file C:\Bitnami\wappstack-5.4.28-0\apache2\htdocs\yii\framework\cli\commands\MigrateCommand.php at line 555
```

What is this `template.php`? How to solve this problem.

Comment: Are u using Yii1 or Yii2 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When generating a new Migration file the Migration command is using a template to create a php file with the basic instructions.

By default Yii is using its own template file but you can define your own. In your case it seems that you set the `templateFile` param but you havn't any template.

In your configuration file find something like :

```
'commandMap' => array(
        'migrate' => array(
            'class' => 'system.cli.commands.MigrateCommand',
            'migrationPath' => 'application.migrations',
            'templateFile' => 'application.migrations.template'//This should be removed
        )
    ),
```

And remove the line `templateFile`